# Why is importing AppKit not working when AppKit is installed on pip3?

Tags: python, appkit

I have installed `AppKit` in pip3, but importing it from `python3` doesn't seem to work. How can I import `AppKit`?

```
❯ pip3 install AppKit
Requirement already satisfied: AppKit in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /Users/kentran/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from AppKit) (4.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pygobject in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from AppKit) (3.38.0)
Requirement already satisfied: flask in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from AppKit) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /Users/kentran/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->AppKit) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycairo>=1.11.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pygobject->AppKit) (1.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->AppKit) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->AppKit) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->AppKit) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from flask->AppKit) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask->AppKit) (1.1.1)
❯
❯ python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import AppKit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'AppKit'
>>>
```

This shows a `ModuleNotFoundError`. Is it under a different namespace?

Comment: `pip3` might not be installing it in the same place you are trying to import from. do `python3 -m pip install AppKit` and then try importing again

Comment: That _still_ doesn't work. *ugh*

Comment: maybe the package is lowercase, `import appkit`?

Comment: no, that refers to a different package.

Comment: same problem, did you find a soution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AppKit you have to install PyObjC:

```
pip3 install -U PyObjC
```

Comment: thanks, but that doesn't seem to work. The same error pops up

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either, which is strange.

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't solve the problem. It just says "Requirement already satisfied"